# Dynamically change minimumLineSpacing in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to dynamically change `minimumLineSpacing` depending on what kind of class the UICollectionViewCell is but I'm unable to find a suitable way to solve this.

I tried doing it via the delegate `- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section`, but I just **wish** that it would pass back a `NSIndexPath` instead of a section. `NSIndexPath` would solve my problem, since, I could just pass `NSIndexPath.row` to my `NSArray` and check that way.

My only approach so far is to check for visible cells in the delegate method above, and get the path that way, but it seems very expensive to have to loop over the cells just to adjust the `minimumLineSpacing`.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up insets in Interface Builder like shown in the screenshot below:

[image: 1]

Will result in something like this:

[image: 2]

Comment: That wasn't my question.. I'm asking, how do I do UIEdgeInsets for a certain cell? So cell for index 3, will have UIEdge 0's.

Answer (score -1):

**Try This Code**

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"SETTING SIZE FOR ITEM AT INDEX %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    CGSize mElementSize = CGSizeMake(104, 104);
    return mElementSize;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10.0;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    return YES;
}

// Layout: Set Edges
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
    (UICollectionView *)collectionView layout: (UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    // return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20,20,20,20);  // top, left, bottom, right
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked.